# 3 Step block matching algorithm for Matlab;

Tags: algorithm, matlab, video-processing

Guyz I need to find a solution for my 2 images to match them. In Matlab there is a simulink for Three-Step Block Match algorithm, but I need to use script for that task. I could not find any function to solve that. Any one help for it or any documentation to implement Three-Step block Matching for image/video processing?

Pseudo code like;

```
 Get frame_1;
     Get block from frame_1;
 Compare this block with another image according to;
    16 px upward, 16 px  down, 16 px  right , 16 px left;
    Get lowest error;
    8 px upward, 8 px down, 8 px  right , 8 px left;
    Get lowest error;
    8 px upward, 8 px  down, 8 px  right , 8 px left;
    Get lowest error;
```

This Algorithm implemented in Simulink but Matlab script does not have it(?). Is there any implementation for that?

Regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited this post